# Рисование кругов по клику мыши в Джава свинг

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Хочу изучить **Swing**. Пишу код, который должен отрисовывать круги по координатам нажатия мыши. Экземпляры `Circle` с координатами `х` и `у`, определяющимися при нажатии мыши, должны заноситься в массив объектов. Потом **JPanel** должен перерисовываться. В цикле, методы `Circle` возвращают координаты, и круги должны отрисовываться. Как сделать правильно чтобы программа работала?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(new TestPanel());
        f.setSize(600, 500);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setTitle("TEST");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}   

class TestPanel extends JPanel{
    LinkedList<Circle> circles = new LinkedList<Circle>();
    Random r = new Random();

    public TestPanel(){
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                circles.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), r.nextInt(51)+30, new Color(r.nextInt(128), r.nextInt(128), r.nextInt(128), r.nextInt(128)+100)));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

            for(Circle c : circles){
                g.setColor(c.getColor());
                g.fillOval(c.getX(), c.getY(), c.getSize(), c.getSize());
            }
        }
    }




import java.awt.Color;

public class Circle{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int size;
    private Color color;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int s, Color c){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        size = s;
        color = c;
    }

    public int getX(){return x;}

    public int getY(){return y;}

    public int getSize(){return size;}

    public Color getColor(){return color;}
}
```

Comment: если вы будете использовать аннотацию Override, то подобные ошибки будут отлавливаться компилятором.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы оверайдите метод `MouseClicked`, а в `MouseAdapter` есть только метод `mouserClicked` ( c маленькой буквы)

Comment: Ой я балда! Там вообще изначально `mousePressed()` задумывался. Наверное когда по документациям рыл - поменял. Сейчас все работает